# Could not check the data in array of array

Tags: protractor, ionic2

I need to check that my app has the data that i give in my array

i have a html like this

```
<ion-card class="card1">
  {{name}}
</ion-card>
<ion-card class="card2" *ngfor="prod of orderlist>
  {{products}}
</ion-card>
```

In my e2e

```
describe('module',()=>{
    it('should have the same data in list array'),() => {
      var quantity = element(by.css('.card2');
        expect(quantity.getText()).toContain(list[0].product[0].check)
    });
//my array 

    var list = [{ name     : 'yoke',
                   product :[{check :'no' },
                              {check :'no' }]
               }];
});
```

what i need is that my app has a field with a value "no", I need to check it weather that data is present in  my card, in the same way i have a big sized array

while testing this in protractor it says that "Cannot find name 'product'. (2304)"

Comment: `var quantity = element(by.css('.card2');` there is a missing closing parenthesis, though I suspect it's just a posting typo. Also, where do you have the `list` defined? Thanks.